# HTML5 offline storage - Dynamically generate .manifest file

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm currently working on a web app with the request that selected pages be accessible offline after downloading. I'm aware of the HTML5 offline storage method and have no problem with it, but as far as I can tell, it's developer specified.

Question is, is there a way in which I can set it up with a function that will write to the .manifest file when, for example, the user clicks a button on the page they'd like cached locally for offline viewing?

The app in its entirety would be far too large to cache locally (not only due to the restrictions of the HTML5 local storage method, but the sheer amount of time it would take).

Suggestions of alternate methods not relying on HTML5 local storage would also be welcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hopefully there is a more elegant solution, but could you assign a unique ID to visitors on first visit (and store in a cookie and a DB)...then each time they add a page, it would add the page and their ID to the DB...and the overall site, when visited, would then dynamically generate the .manifest file to include all of the items matching their cookie'd ID?

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. Basically I'd need a web app which utilizes the local storage capabilities on user request so that the person could take the tablet to an offline area and still present/have access to the pages required. The problems I've run into would be the user not saving every page they need to successfully navigate to their chosen pages as well as the space constraints. However, your solution would work, I think, in other situations. I don't think we'll be pursuing this solution at the moment, but I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.